# mvvm light wpf unregister

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have some problems with mvvm light. Using [MVVMLight](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views)

For example i registering in _firstViewModel on message

```
FirstViewModel()
{
        Messenger.Default.Register<GrapCommunication>(this, (emp) =>
        {
            if (selectedNumber != null && emp.assetSelector.ContainsKey(selectedNumber))
                S.Points.Add(new DataPoint(DateTime.Now.ToOADate(), emp.assetSelector[selectedNumber].Last_Value));
        });
}
```

When i am switching on the _secondViewModel. The _firstViewModel still getting data. I tried to do something like

```
private void ExecuteSecondViewCommand()
{
    CurrentViewModel = MainViewModel._secondViewModel;
    Messenger.Default.Unregister(_firstViewModel);
}
```

Does not helps.

Comment: Is your reference to `_firstViewModel` still valid where you're calling `Unregister`?  In other words, it isn't pointing to a different view model or is `null`?

Comment: Yes it's all rigth _firstViewModel!=null

Comment: Is it only the <GrapCommunication> type messages you want to unregister from? MVVM Light has a Cleanup method in ViewModelBase which should unregister a ViewModel from *all* messaging types. Could be worth a punt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to indicate the object type as well    `Messenger.Default.Unregister<GrapCommunication>(_firstViewModel)`. And make sure that `_firstViewModel` is the same instance of **FirstViewModel** that registered the call.

You can also use the **token** parameter of the Messenger, this will allow you to register multiple instances of the same object on the same ViewModel and gives you some extra information about the registration.

`Messenger.Default.Register<GrapCommunication>(this, "RegistrationDescription",(emp) =>
        {...}`

And  `Messenger.Default.Unregister(_firstViewModel, "RegistrationDescription");`